# Alternative for toArray to increase perfomance in terms of time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, newrelic, toarray

I use newrelic to know the stats for the performance of my website and I got to know a get command to an entity is taking too much time. 
The segment **"MongoDB ms.users toArray"** is taking around 248,000 ms.

Any suggestions to improve the time?

Comment: A "seven seconds" surely that is several thousand results ( if not tens of thousands ) and you really should be using a cursor response, and likely stream output. Both in terms of time and of course memory usage. But the real question is what could you possibly need that many results for? I sense you have some other code processing this result that is the real problem. The general idea of querying databases is to make them do the work in processing, and not the application.